# SocketError.NoBufferSpaceAvailable

Tags: c#, sockets

My application outputs UDP message through a Socket. This has worked fine until now, but a recently deployment to a virtualized OS has given me problems with SocketExceptions with SocketError NoBufferSpaceAvailable.

In normal cases, a UDP message is transmitted every 1 second. However I often see that 2-3 message in a row are subject to the mentioned exception. What will be the best strategy to handle this? The strategy that comes to my mind is:

```
int trials = 0;
while(trials <= 5)
{
    try
    {
        trials++;
        _socket.Send(...);
    }
    catch(SocketException e)
    {
        if(e.SocketErrorCode == SocketError.NoBufferSpaceAvailable)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(100);
        }
        else
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

What is the standard approach in a case like this?

Answer (score 1):

You have to check the size of your send packet. Also, do you have a character or a sequence telling the server that it's the end of it ?

Comment: So something like that I send from an appropriate offset until the entire buffer has been transmitted?